# Handling Syntax in Order to Perform Calculations in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Suppose we have a set of cells that contain pairs of values (a_i, a_j).  Is there a way to have Excel take the difference between these values?  What is the easiest way to allow Excel to understand the bracket and comma syntax so that it can take the difference and place the calculated value below / beside the brackets?  Note that some of the cells in which these values occur may be merged cells.  Specifically, within the range A1:C10 there might be 3 merged cells among all the other cells within the range. It would be ideal to be able to simply highlight this range (or just the individual block cells together) and have the difference be calculated for the cells, merged or not, that contain pairs of values in the above format.  That said, a solution that works for a single cell, merged or not, would be very helpful as well.

Comment: You will most likely need to use some kind of UDF for this.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks, are there specific VBA methods that might be helpful in creating it?

Comment: I would replace `(` and `)` with nothing and then use `Split` with `,` as delimeter

Comment: @simoco Will an additional step be necessary if some of the cells in which these values are found are merged?

Comment: @pnuts That might work, and yes negative values may occur.  The only thing that concerns me about that is the merged cell issue, which I should have stated in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this small macro:

```
Sub KalKulator()
    Dim zum As Variant
    For Each r In Selection
        v = r.Text
        ary = Split(Replace(Replace(v, ")", ""), "(", ""), ",")
        zum = CDbl(ary(0)) + CDbl(ary(1))
        r.Value = r.Value & CStr(zum)
    Next r
End Sub
```

If you select cells like:

```
(5,6)
(8,99)
```

it will convert them into:

```
(5,6)11
(8,99)107
```

**NOTE#1**

As coded, it will **not** properly handle merged cells.

**EDIT#1:**

This version will handle **some** instances of merged cells and corrects the **"-"** as well

```
Sub KalKulator2()
    Dim zum As Variant
    For Each r In Selection
        If r.Value <> "" Then
            v = r.Text
            ary = Split(Replace(Replace(v, ")", ""), "(", ""), ",")
            zum = CDbl(ary(0)) - CDbl(ary(1))
            r.Value = r.Value & CStr(zum)
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Before:
[image: before]

After:

[image: After]

Comment: Thanks Gary, that works great. I see you and Simoco thought the same way about the problem.  Do you have any hints as to how to modify this to handle an arbitrary selection some of which contains tuples and some of which don't?

Comment: @Gary It gives me a range error but still correctly computes.  To answer pnuts it does seem to work on negatives, though I have only tried in cases where both numbers are negative or both positive.

Comment: @pnuts You're right, it will work work for one merged cell but not multiple merged cells.  The way things are set up it would only help significantly if I could ctrl-select multiple, arbitrary cells and still have it work.

Comment: @pnuts I modified Gary's formula to be CDbl(ary(1)) - CDbl(ary(0)) before using it, I should have mentioned that before, my apologies.